# Yii::t with a edit link

Tags: php, yii

i am using Yii:t() to do the translation. but i want to add an edit link beside these translated text. so i can just click on the link, then it will take me to the edit page, and i can easily do the update.

the thing i am currently doing is adding a place holder to the text. that is 'translated text#my place holder#';

then i use Yii's afterRender() to preg_replace these place holder with some html tags, so i can manipulate using javascript later.

however if these html tags are put into  tag, it would break.

so how can i replace the place holder with html tags and handle ,, .etc.

i know yii has a translate module , but the link it add will take me to the admin page, show all translation, not the exact one.

Comment: you should try to be more specific about your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a translation with a link inside of it, use this structure:

```
<?php
echo Yii::t(
  'login', 
  'New user? {link:signup}Create an account{/link}',
  array(
    '{link:signup}'=>'<a href="'.CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('/user/signUp')).'">',
    '{/link}'=>'</a>',
  )
);
?>
```

You use placeholder for link start and link end.

Comment: but i already has a lot of codes using yii::t(), if i do it like you suggested, i would need to modify my old codes one by one, not so ideal 。